# Colors in bar charts plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to set colors in bar chart by using Plotly with the dataframe below :

```
print(df)
    +----+--------------------+----------+--------------+----------+
    |    |   week of creation | status   | status_odj   |   number |
    |----+--------------------+----------+--------------+----------|
    |  0 |                 23 | re       | ko           |        3 |
    |  1 |                 23 | re       | ok           |        9 |
    |  2 |                 23 | re       | autre_ok     |        6 |
    |  3 |                 23 | re       | autre_ec     |        7 |
    |  4 |                 23 | re       | autre_ko     |        2 |
    |  5 |                 23 | ri       | ko           |        4 |
    |  6 |                 23 | ri       | ok           |        7 |
    |  7 |                 23 | ri       | autre_ok     |        2 |
    |  8 |                 23 | ri       | autre_ec     |        3 |
    |  9 |                 23 | ri       | autre_ko     |        8 |
    | 10 |                 24 | re       | ko           |        2 |
    | 11 |                 24 | re       | ok           |       11 |
    | 12 |                 24 | re       | autre_ok     |        5 |
    | 13 |                 24 | re       | autre_ec     |        4 |
    | 14 |                 24 | re       | autre_ko     |        2 |
    | 15 |                 24 | ri       | ko           |        5 |
    | 16 |                 24 | ri       | ok           |       10 |
    | 17 |                 24 | ri       | autre_ok     |        2 |
    | 18 |                 24 | ri       | autre_ec     |        0 |
    | 19 |                 24 | ri       | autre_ko     |        9 |
    +----+--------------------+----------+--------------+----------+
```

I would like for each "week of creation", one bar for "status" *re* and one for "status" *ri* in which there is one color for each "status_odj".

With Plotly Express I can generate one bar for each "status" with one color for each "status_odj" but I cannot seperate "week of creation" into separate bars :

```
import plotly.express as px
fig=px.bar(df, x="status", y="number", color="status_odj")
fig.show()
```

[chart with plotly express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt9VR.png)

With Plotly GO I can generate one bar for each "status" and split "week of creation" into seprate bars but I cannot set one color for each "status_odj" :

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df_ri=df[df["status"]=="ri"]
df_re=df[df["status"]=="re"]
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_ri["week of creation"],y = df_ri["number"]))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_re["week of creation"],y = df_re["number"]))
fig.show()
```

[chart with plotly Go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGBcI.png)

I need a kind of mix of both technics... Please, do you have suggestions to help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add color in the `add_trace` function you can use this code:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_1["..."],y = df_1["..."], marker=dict(color=df_1["..."])))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_2["..."],y = df_2["..."], marker=dict(color=df_2["..."])))
```

final code like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df_ri=df[df["status"]=="ri"]
df_re=df[df["status"]=="re"]
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_ri["week of creation"],y = df_ri["number"], marker=dict(color=df_ri["status_odj"])))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_re["week of creation"],y = df_re["number"], marker=dict(color=df_re["status_odj"])))
fig.show()
```

Comment: thank you ! it works, I add a fucntion to manage a dico of colors :) (see my answer)
But now I'm wondering how to manage titles for each bar

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I made some modifications:

```
dico_color ={
  "ko": "red",
  "ok": "green",
  "autre_ec": "blue",
  "autre_ok" : "darkgreen",
  "autre_ko" : "darkred"
}

#Generate a list of color from de dico of color
def colorfunc(df,col_name,dico_color={}):
  color_val=[]
  labelList =  list(df[col_name].values)
  for i in range(len(labelList)):
    color_tmp=dico_color[df[df[col_name]==labelList[i]][col_name].values[0]]
    color_val.append(color_tmp)
  return color_val

fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_ri["week of creation"],y = df_ri["number"], marker=dict(color=colorfunc(df_ri,"status_odj",dico_color))))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = df_re["week of creation"],y = df_re["number"], marker=dict(color=colorfunc(df_re,"status_odj",dico_color))))
```

It works properly. Now, I would like to add a title *ri* and *re* close to each bar for all weeks. How can I do that?

Comment: If this is an update to your question please remove this answer and update your question